# a damning observation

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The Commons health select committee noted last December that “the number of young people receiving treatment has risen from just 25% to around 40% of those with a diagnosable condition pre-pandemic”. But, the MPs added, “it is not acceptable that more than half of young people do not receive the mental health support they need” – ***a damning observation***.

Can you please tell me what **a damning observation** means? Is the writer suggesting that he doesn't believe what the MPs said?

Comment: "damning" here means that it accuses someone of doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

"Damning" here means that it accuses someone of doing something wrong. The MP's, in observing that "more than half of young people do not receive the mental health support they need," are accusing those who would be responsible for helping them of not doing enough to help. See [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/damning).